# Change Data Adapter password for MS SQL server database in Jaspersoft studio

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I have created project in Jaspersoft studio sometime before. Recently, I have changed MS SQL Server login Password.
From then onwards; when I'm trying to create dataset, I am getting the below error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'.
```

I searched in Google, but I could not get relevant and proper URL to suggest on how to do.

Can anybody please help me on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found Solution.

Navigate to **Repository Explorer**

Go to the required Data Adapter for which the Password needs to be change

Change Password there.

Done.